# The problem of counting members according to roles

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I recently updated to the version of discord.js v12 and since then I have a problem with this command.
From what can this error arise?
I think I updated ok depending on the new version

```
 Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined
```

```
 let guild = await message.guild.members.fetch();
 let trstRole        = '-';
 let memberCountTrst = guild.roles.cache.get(trstRole).members.size;
 let onlineMembersCount =  guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status !== "offline").size;
 let offlineMembersCount = guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status == "offline").size;
 const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(colours.red_light)
            .setTitle("Stats")
            .addField("Trst role members: ", memberCountTrst)
            .addField("Online Members: ", onlineMembersCount)
            .addField("Offline Members: ", offlineMembersCount)
```

Answer (score 0):

A misrepresentation of the `Guild` object is the problem that is happening here.
In the very first line, you define it as the member collection of the guild (`await message.guild.members.fetch()`).

Because it is not an actual guild structure, it does not have a `GuildMemberManager`, nor a `RoleManager`.

I think what you meant to do was

```js
await guild.members.fetch()
//caches all members
const guild = message.guild //pretty redundant but... you do you
const memberCountTrst = guild.roles.cache.get(trstRole).members.size
// and further code here
```